# Filter foreach index value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, filter, indexof

How to filter index value in foreach Javascript with condition if

> last_login = null

then store the filtered values to

> this.searchLogin

Image below is the ouput of: **console.log(obj);**

[image]

Here' what I've done so far:

```
try {
   this.searchTrigger = true
   var obj = this.list;

   this.searchLogin = [];

   for (let i=0; i < obj.length; ++i){
       if(obj.filter( x => obj[i].profile.last_login === null)){
          this.searchLogin.push(obj[i]);
       }
   }

console.log('This are obj data passed to search login',this.searchLogin);
```

Comment: Do you want to `searchLogin` to contain the object or `obj[i].profile.last_login`?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Yes I want to push new filtered array values to searchLogin, with the condition of `if profile.last_login = null`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = [
{ profile: { last_login: null } },
{ profile: { last_login: true } },
{ profile: { last_login: null } },
{ profile: { last_login: true } },
{ profile: { last_login: null } }]



//With filter and map
console.log("With filter and map: ", 
        obj.map((x, i) => ({ ...x.profile, i }))
            .filter(x => !x.last_login)
            .map(x => x.i));



//With reduce
console.log("With reduce: ",
        obj.reduce((p, c, i) => (!c.profile.last_login && p.push(i), p), [])
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some points that need to be noted

- `filter` function will return an array and even if it empty (no matched results), it will still be evaluated as true i.e. your if condition will always be executed
- The `if` condition has a filter function inside a for loop which means that you are unnecessarily checking condition for same object for all the objects in array i.e. for each object the filter function will either return empty array or array of all the objects.

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and store the `last_login` information in the resultant array

```
this.searchLogin = this.list.reduce((a,c) => c.profile.last_login === null ? a.concat(c.profile.last_login) : a, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to save the results explicitly to an array again, the filter on array by itself will create an results array based on the filter condition.

For more on filter,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

In your case,

```
 this.searchLogin = obj.filter( x => x.profile.last_login === null);
```

would do the trick.

Comment: Does this check all the index array values here in `this.list`? Thanks :) Will try this out.

Comment: filter checks all the values in the array. please try out let know.

Comment: `try {
      this.searchTrigger = true
      var obj = this.list;
      this.searchLogin = obj.filter( x => x.profile.last_login === null);
      console.log('This are obj data passed to search login',this.searchLogin);
}
`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-heigj7   created a stackblitz for you with dummy values to replicate your object list and the expected results. Please free to edit the same and share with your list values if its still not working